# csv write array to file in python, How to delete the additional row

Tags: python, file, csv, file-io

I try to write array to file:

```
import csv
ofile = open('result.csv', "w")

writer=csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=',',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
a=[[1,2],[3,4]]
for i in a:
    writer.writerow(i)
ofile.close()
```

the target file will be:

```
1,2

3,4
```

I want to write file without mid empty line here

I want:

```
1,2
3,4
```

How should I do it?

Comment: How do you open the file when you get that empty line?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're on Python 2.x.

Open the file in `'wb'` mode instead of `'w'` so change this line `ofile = open('result.csv', "w")` to this  `ofile = open('result.csv', "wb")`. That should fix the problem